# There is any difference between heilang skills and normal skills?

Tags: black-desert-online

Some of the tamer skills say Heilang: in the title[image]

Are those the Skills that Heilang use by himself?

Or are there another difference with the rest of the skills?

I'm sure that is not just the skill that he cast with you because Void Lightning Specifies that in the info and don't say "Heilang:" in the title [image]